# Select all items from column SQL

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

How  can I select all records from column name if condition in example is not defined with sql statement where.

Example:

```
function getData($condition){
     if($condition ==null){
           $condition = '*';
     }
     sql = "select * from table where name=$condition"
}
```

It's just example, but '*' is not working in select. Any help?

Comment: you wanna set field name?

Comment: i edited my question, can you look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
function getData($condition){
     if($condition ==null){
           $condition = '1';
     }else{
           $condition = "`name`={$condition}";
     }
     sql = "select * from table where $condition";
}
```

Comment: @user2899587 for using "*" you should use "like" instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getData($condition){
     if($condition ==null){
           $condition = '1=1';
     }
     else
     {
           $condition = 'Name='+$condition;
     }
     sql = "select * from table where $condition"
}
```